# nginx accept both http1 and http2

Tags: nginx, http2

I built a thunderbird plugin running on tb v45, it uses nsIXMLHttpRequest and XMLHttpRequest to post and get data from a server, the server has been set up on nginx using the http2 protocol.

the log is

```
  "POST /service/v2/api HTTP/1.1" 502 1266 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Thunderbird/45.4.0 Lightning/4.7.4"
```

hence a bad gateway. I thought that this http setting was backwards compatable.

```
   listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
   listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
```

How can I make the nginx setup accept http1 or can nsIXMLHttpRequest send the correct headers so it uses http2?

Answer (score 0):

This was really totally nothing to do with the headers, but ngnix and the settings

Thunderbird didnt like the ssl cert and ciphers on the http2 setting, it was fine on http1 so I had to set this in the nginx.conf

Seems that Thunderbird didnt like some old Ciphers, then checked this against https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.htm for pre modification and saw that Handshake Simulations were failing on the old ciphers. Hence with the settings below I was able to get Thunderbird working with the API and SSL cert correctly. Before I had a B rating on Qualys now its an A+ and everything is perfectly working

```
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
 ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
```